# Implementation of mapping Hexagons in functional programming and problems with Lists

Tags: c#, list, select, functional-programming, mapping

I'm looking to create a framework for creating board/strategy games like CIV in unity however I intend on testing the function in vanilla c# before I implement it so in order to create symmetrical hexagonal grids that look like the following

```
 __    __    __    __    __    __    __
/13\__/14\__/15\__/16\__/17\__/18\__/19\
\__/07\__/08\__/09\__/10\__/11\__/12\__/
/00\__/01\__/02\__/03\__/04\__/05\__/06\
\__/  \__/  \__/  \__/  \__/  \__/  \__/
```

I need to have every other row reduced by 1 so that moving in any direction is simply increasing or decreasing the index by 7, 13 or 6

My current issue is that my struct:

```cs
struct hexagon{
    public int xpos;
    public int ypos;
}
```

is as of my understanding not being understood by the class `List`
and so my code:

```cs
int width = 7;
int height = 7;
int l = width*2-1;
int r = 1;

Func<int,int> xhex = i => ((i%l) < width) ? 2*(i%l) : 2*(i%l)-l;
Func<int,int> yhex = i => ((i%l) < width) ? 2*(i/l) : 2*(i/l)+1;

var grid = new List<hexagon> [width * height - height/2].Select((h,i)=>{
    h.xpos = xhex(i)*r*1.5;
    h.ypos = yhex(i)*r*0.8660; // sqrt(3/2)
    });
```

is throwing the error

> 'List' does not contain a definition for 'xpos' and no accessible extension method 'xpos' accepting a first argument of type 'List' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [Grid-Parse]

I'm also not really sure if the function `Select` will accept the index overload is there anything I can use that is just as elegant?

Comment: `xpos` isn’t public

Comment: I've just made it public and it is still throwing the error sadly

Comment: You created an array of `List<hexagon>` so you select on the array and an element of that array is a `List<hexagon>` not a hexagon. And a `List<hexagon>` does not have a xpos field.  That is exactly what the error tells you. Why on earth do you need an array of a List<T>?

Comment: By the way you are using integers but you multiplying with fractions(doubles). You should clear up your thoughts about the used datatypes. As it is it should not work.

Comment: thankyou your right I hadn't caught that the xpos and ypos should be floats ort doubles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks as though you're trying to initialise a sequence of hexagons. Use [Enumerable.Range](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.range) to generate a sequence of integers, and then `Select` to create the hexagons:

```
var grid = Enumerable.Range(0, width * height - height / 2)
    .Select(i => new Hexagon(xhex(i) * r * 1.5, yhex(i) * r * 0.8660));
```

This is assuming that `Hexagon` looks like this:

```
public struct Hexagon
{
    public double xpos;
    public double ypos;

    public Hexagon(double xpos, double ypos)
    {
        this.xpos = xpos;
        this.ypos = ypos;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this solution would help u:

```
    struct hexagon
       {
         public int xpos;
         public int ypos;
       }


        int width = 7;
        int height = 7;
        int l = width * 2 - 1;
        int r = 1;
        int counterx = 0;
        int countery = 0;

        Func<int, int> xhex = i => ((i % l) < width) ? 2 * (i % l) : 2 * (i % l) - l;
        Func<int, int> yhex = i => ((i % l) < width) ? 2 * (i / l) : 2 * (i / l) + 1;


        var grid = new List<hexagon>[width * height - height / 2].Select(h => new hexagon()
        {
            xpos = (int)(xhex(counterx++) * r * 1.5),
            ypos = (int)(yhex(countery++) * r * 0.8660)
        });
```

Comment: Still the same `List<T>[]` craziness.

Comment: I did what he wanted, a way to bypass the error . I don't care if the expected result is a grid or not. Do you see that is he asking for something else?

Comment: @ralph - I'm not sure i understand what the purpose of the list is over an array. changing it to ```new hexagon[width * height - height]``` throws the error ```The type arguments for method 'Enumerable.Select<TSource, TResult>(IEnumerable<TSource>, Func<TSource, int, TResult>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly. [Grid-Parse]```